# file transfer mechanism (FTP/SFTP/SSHFTP) using purely PL/SQL in Oracle 19c database

Tags: oracle

In Oracle 19C database, can we transfer files in FTP/SFTP/SSHFTP using purely PL/SQL? Please give me link to accomplish this if possible. if not then please suggest the other ways. We want to process 500 files through sFTP daily.

Comment: You have Java stored procedures in Oracle 19c, why limit yourself to PL/SQL

Comment: Hi Tony, Can you share the link for java procedure. Thanks VR

Comment: We have use http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ internally to develop this kind of functionality. Any competent Java developer should be able to develop this as a Java stored procedure, it is fairly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

Tim Hall made a really cool package to do just this using the packages UTL_TCP and UTL_FILE. The specification and body are available in
https://oracle-base.com/dba/miscellaneous/ftp.pks
https://oracle-base.com/dba/miscellaneous/ftp.pkb

With the package, you can then send files

```
DECLARE
  l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_conn := ftp.login('ftp.company.com', '21', 'ftpuser', 'ftppassword');
  ftp.binary(p_conn => l_conn);
  ftp.put(p_conn      => l_conn,
          p_from_dir  => 'MY_DOCS',
          p_from_file => 'jobs_get.gif',
          p_to_file   => '/u01/app/oracle/jobs_put.gif');
  ftp.logout(l_conn);
END;
/
```

or retrieve

```
DECLARE
  l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_conn := ftp.login('ftp.company.com', '21', 'ftpuser', 'ftppassword');
  ftp.binary(p_conn => l_conn);
  ftp.get(p_conn      => l_conn,
          p_from_file => '/u01/app/oracle/product/9.2.0.1.0/sysman/reporting/gif/jobs.gif',
          p_to_dir    => 'MY_DOCS',
          p_to_file   => 'jobs_get.gif');
  ftp.logout(l_conn);
END;
/
```

There are more functionalities that come with the package. Check it out here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ftp-from-plsql

Comment: Thanks a lot Norman, You have given code for FTP, Is there any other way to do SFTP excluding the last URL you have given? We want to process 500 files through sFTP daily.

Comment: Hi Norman, awaiting for your reply.

Comment: are you still waiting or you got it eventually ? :-)

Comment: Yes, I am still waiting